# Magento category meta title disappears with custom template

Tags: magento, title, categories, meta

I'm using a Magento template called Bootstrapped (http://bootstrapped.magenthon.com), and am editing this template to fit our needs.
Since our website's navigation is based on (sub-)categories, we use a roadmap to help guide the user through the system.

Therefore, we have edited the main category of our products with the following custom XML:

```
<!-- Remove Breadcrumbs -->
<reference name="head"><remove name="breadcrumbs" /></reference>

<!-- Set Roadmap template -->
<reference name="content"><reference name="category.products">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="roadmap" template="alphabase/catalog/roadmap.phtml">
        <action method="setData"><name>roadmap_type</name><value>onderdelen</value></action>
        <action method="setData"><name>maxlevels</name><value>6</value></action>
    </block>

    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/view.roadmap.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="setData"><name>roadmap_type</name><value>onderdelen</value></action>
    <action method="setData"><name>per_row</name><value>4</value></action>

    <reference name="products.list">
        <action method="setData"><name>roadmap_type</name><value>onderdelen</value></action>
    </reference>
</reference></reference>
```

Now when I apply this update, the website's meta title does not show any of the 'breadcrumbs' that the user has followed so far, it only shows the shop's name.

However, when I remove the custom XML, the meta title neatly displays the 'breadcrumbs' in the title, followed by the suffix we have set through the admin panel.

I have compared the original file in /app/design/frontend/package/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml with the file I am using, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I would say it has something to do with the Bootstrapped theme I'm using, but then why would it work when I remove this simple custom XML?

Also, the title does change when I set a meta title in the category settings, and it adds the suffix, but it does not show the 'path'. The website also displays my meta description when I set one.

I have also looked at the file in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php but nothing's there that would give me a hint on what goes wrong.

Could anyone help me get to the right direction?

EDIT: I have also tried removing the file in templates/page/html/head.phtml from my custom theme, just to see if that does anything wrong, but nothing changed after that, either.

EDIT2: My sub-categories use the parent category settings.

Comment: You have to watch out with third party templates. Sometimes they skip implementing certain features. This often means reading the base template code and adding it back into the template you just bought, or demanding that the developer repair their mess-up and add the code in that should have been there in the first place so the rest of their customers aren't left out to dry.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I hope I've investigated the template build enough to solve this problem myself. There's no code in the template that alters any code in the /app/code/ folder, so there should be a 'quick' fix, right?

Answer (score 0):

Old question - however I found that the following in general kills meta title

```
<remove name="breadcrumbs" />
```

Once you add that to any layout, the meta title returns blank.